# Difference between dot() and ddot() for Matx in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

What is the difference between the ddot() and dot() member functions of the Matx class in OpenCV?
The documentation is cryptic.

Comment: What's cryptic about it? `ddot` does the calculation using (and returns) `double`, whereas `dot` uses the actual data type (the first template parameter) of the `Matx`. (e.g. you have a `Matx` holding `uint8_t`, then you probably don't want to calculate the dot product using 8bit integers as well, since it's likely to overflow)

Comment: I guess the part that felt cryptic was the meaning of “default precision” in the case of dot(). You have cleared that up by telling me it uses the type in the first template parameter

Comment: OK. [Here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp#L716)'s the implementation, the difference should be clear from that.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is clear now.

Comment: The implement link [had rotted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), here's a permlink for it: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/0052d46b8e33c7bfe0e1450e4bff28b88f455570/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp#L741